# show that an integral is a measure, is use of double union legal?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I made a proof to an excercise, the sollution of the excercise we are given is completely different(they used a lemma from earlier), can you please check if what I did was legal, and if the proof is correct?

> Let f be a nonnegative, simple function on a Measure space
>   $(X,A,\mu)$. Show that
>
> $\nu(B)$ = $\int_B f\,d\mu$ defines a measure $\nu$ on $(X,A)$.

**1.** Since $\nu(\emptyset)=\int_\emptyset f \, d\mu = \int\textbf{1}_\emptyset f \, d\mu=0$. The first condition is satisfied.

(**Why is the integral over the emptyset really 0?**)

**2.**
I need to show the criteria of countable addivity for disjont measurable sets.

Assume therefore that $\{B_i\}$ is a disjoint sequence of sets. Since $f$ is simple we can partition $X$ in sets where $f$ is constant on these sets, these sets are also measurable.

On set $C_j$, $f$ is equal to $c_j$, assume that we have $M$ of these.

$$D_{i,j} = B_i \cap C_j$$

Now we have that since the $C$s for a partition $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N},j \in M}D_{i,j}=\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}B_i$.

But can I instead work with a "double union"-like this?:

$$\nu\left(\bigcup_{i \in N} B_i\right) = \nu\left(\bigcup_M \left( \bigcup_\mathbb{N} D_{i,j} \right) \right) = \int_{\bigcup_M \left(\bigcup_\mathbb{N}D_{i,j}\right)} f\,d \mu = $$

$$\int\left(\textbf{1}_{\cup_{\mathbb{N},j=1}}+\textbf{1}_{\cup_{\mathbb{N},j=2}}+\cdots+\textbf{1}_{\cup_{\mathbb{N},j=M}}\right) f \, d\mu = \sum_{j=1}^Mc_j* \mu\left(\bigcup_{\mathbb{N},j=M} D_{i,j}\right) = \sum_{j=1}^Mc_j\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu(D_{i,j})$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^Mc_j*\mu(D_{i,j})=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\int_{B_i}f \, d\mu$$

In the last equality I used that for each Bi had divided this set in M where the value in each of these is constant. Is this proof correct?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that $f$ is *simple*? The integral over the empty set is zero because the integrand is the zero function.

Comment: A simple function is defined in my book as a function that only takes finitely many values, and is measurable. However it would be interesting to know if the statement would hold if it wasnt simple only measurable(or integrable)? For the emptyset do you mean that: $\int_{\emptyset}fd \mu=\int \textbf{1}_{\emptyset} fd \mu=\int0d\mu=0*\mu(X)=0$?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean when it concerns the empty set. There is no need for $f$ to be simple. In general if $g_{n}$ is measurable and nonnegative for $n=1,2,\dots$
then $g:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_{n}$ is measurable and nonnegative,
and this with $\int gd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int g_{n}d\mu$. You
can apply that on $g_{n}=f1_{B_{n}}$ and $g=f1_{B}$ where the sets
$B_{n}$ are measurable and disjoint and have union $B=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}$.
It leads directly to $\nu\left(B\right)=\int gd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int g_{n}d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\nu\left(B_{n}\right)$.

Comment: @drhab Thank you so much! Maybe what you used is too complicated for me, but you used that an infinite sum of measuurable and nonegative functions are measurable, and that you could move the integral sign inside of an infinite sum. I know that if we know that a limit of measurable functions converges then it is measurable, is that why you chose nonnegative?, so that the sum is increasing and hence it must converge pointwise? And to move the integral sign inside the sum, you used the montone convergence theorem for help?

Comment: Yes, in your comment you mention the essential points. As long as you are working with nonnegatives in measure-theory you are somehow 'on the safe side'. The sum is *non-decreasing* - a bit weaker than increasing - but that is enough for pointwise convergence. Ironically the fact that you must do this for a *simple* function seems to make things *complicated*.

Comment: @drhab Thank you very much!, this was very helpful!